# hibernate not determining entity classes as field variables

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create runtime configuration for annotated classes as I am using other project as library (contains only `HibernateUtil` and `hibernate.cfg.xml`). Now the problem is that when I pass only one class in this configuration, everything works fine but when I introduce more then one classes, test fails as following stack trace:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite setUp
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.model.Person, at table: ranking, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ranking_observer)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at com.utlity.HibernateUtil.configurationSetup(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at com.model.RankingTest.setUp(RankingTest.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

Following is my main class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ranking")
public class Ranking {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ranking_id")
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "ranking_subject")
    protected Person subject;

    @Column(name = "ranking_observer")
    protected Person observer;

    @Column(name = "ranking_skill")
    protected Skill skill;

    @Column(name = "ranking_numbers")
    protected Integer ranking;
```

test case

```
public class RankingTest {

protected SessionFactory factory;

@BeforeSuite
public void setUp() {
    factory = HibernateUtil.configurationSetup(Ranking.class, Person.class, Skill.class);
}

@Test
public void testSetup() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(factory);
}
}
```

and hibernateUtil

```
public static SessionFactory configurationSetup(Class<?>... classes) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(clazz);
        }
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated and if more info is needed, please tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a relationship between two types of objects: `Ranking` and `Person`. The `@Column`-annotation is not usually used for those situations, AFAIK using it results in creating a blob column into which the Person instance is serialized.

You'd want to use the `@ManyToOne` annotation instead (and it's inverse `@OneToMany` in the `Person`-class. More information about entity relationships can be found in [the Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html).